# Show allowed origins of webserver configured with CORS

Tags: tomcat, cors

i am trying to understand how cors works.
The tomat cors filter is throwing a 403 Status if i use a origin which is not configured in my web.xml cors config. The valid cors reponse looks like this :

```
$ curl -H "Origin: http://test.de" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS --verbose http://localhost:8080/static
/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x20830d8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x20830d8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS /static/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://test.de
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.de
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,x-requested-with
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 09:55:38 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

the invalid cors reponse looks like this:

```
$ curl -H "Origin: http://test2.de" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS --verbose http://localhost:8080/stati
c/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x8a30d8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x8a30d8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS /static/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://test2.de
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 10:04:09 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I thought there would be also a 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.de
part within the 403 response? Is there any way to find out the allowed origins of a url? Or is this the wanted behavour? Is the jetty cors implementation working the same way as the tomcat?

And at least, i am a bit confused, that the tomcat cors filter is only looking at the origin header. If i do not add any origin header the request is processed with reponse status code 200 and i get the whole content.

With other words, it the same origin policy is only a problem for browser who send the origin with each request?

Ah and one last question, the preflight request is "optional" request? If i use curl to make a cors request without a preflight request, i get the 200 response too. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

My first step went to the official [Tomcat CORS Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) documentation. There I noticed two things:

1. [Tomcat CORS Filter FlowChart](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png)
2. Tomcat CORS Filter classname: `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter`

First, I checked the [Tomcat CORS Filter FlowChart](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png) and performed a lot of CURL requests to find a solution to the "problem". No progress.

Second, I checked the Tomcat CORS Filter class source code -> [GrepCode.com: org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java#CorsFilter.parseAndStore(java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String)). There I noticed that the HTTP POST requests are somehow required to have the `Content-Type` HTTP header filled. So I simply set it to `text/plain`. Then the Tomcat server application started to return the HTTP CORS headers correctly and also for HTTP 403 (Access Forbidden) and HTTP 200 (OK) return statuses.

Example:

```
$ curl -v -c c.txt -b c.txt -H "Origin: http://example.com" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST http://some-server.com:8080/trunk/rest/some/thing
```

HTTP request:

```
POST /trunk/rest/some/thing HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: some-server.com:8080
Accept: */*
Cookie: JSESSIONID=SOMEID
Origin: http://example.com
Content-Type: text/plain
```

HTTP response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie,X-JSessionId
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 08:04:49 GMT
```

The `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter` class is said to be implemented according to the [W3C CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) specification. Maybe the real answer to the problem is hidden somewhere in there.

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: That was exactly what solved my issue. On certain scenarios I would have gotten 403 and on other occasions I would have gotten 200, and I couldn't have figured it out, and eventually it was the missing 'Content-Type' header. Silly issue. Kudos on the find.

Answer (score 0):

Since CORS is for enabling cross origin access, the browser (http client)  has to inform the server about the origin of the code that wants to access the service so that the server can decide whether the configuration at the server side is permitting the origin to access the service. The Origin header informs the server that it is a request for CORS ; if Origin header is not there then it is treated a same origin access and hence CORS response headers are not added and 200 response is returned.

For all Origin that are not configured in the web.xml 403 response will be returned; this is an expected behavior. There is no way to find the list of allowed origins.